# How do I keep track of my correct answer in an array list after shuffling it?

Tags: java, android

Code:

```
       private void getAnswers(int Type) {
    /* 
     * Getting answers here
     */
    //int randomValue = random(4);
    try { 
    String answers_list[][] = {
            {"Answer 1-1", "Answer 2-1", "Answer 3-1", "Answer 4-1"}, 
            {"Answer 1-2", "Answer 2-2", "Answer 3-2", "Answer 4-2"},
            {"Answer 1-3", "Answer 2-3", "Answer 3-3", "Answer 4-3"},
            {"Answer 1-4", "Answer 2-4", "Answer 3-4", "Answer 4-4"},
            {"Answer 1-5", "Answer 2-5", "Answer 3-5", "Answer 4-5"}} ;
    //answer1.setText(answers_list[Type][randomValue+1 > 3 ? (randomValue+0)-4 : randomValue+0]); 
    //answer2.setText(answers_list[Type][randomValue+2 > 3 ? (randomValue+1)-3 : randomValue+1]); 
    //answer3.setText(answers_list[Type][randomValue+3 > 3 ? (randomValue+2)-2 : randomValue+2]); 
    //answer4.setText(answers_list[Type][randomValue+0 > 3 ? (randomValue+3)-4 : randomValue+3]);
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(answers_list[Type]));
    answer1.setText(answers_list[Type][0]);
    answer2.setText(answers_list[Type][1]);
    answer3.setText(answers_list[Type][2]);
    answer4.setText(answers_list[Type][3]);
    /*for (int rows = 0; rows < answer&*list.length; rows++){
    for (int cols = 0; cols < answers_list[rows].length; cols++){   
      }
        }*/
    } catch(Exception ex){
    answer1.setText("Error "+ex);
    }



}
```

I want `"Answer 1-1"`, `"Answer 1-2"`, `"Answer 1-3"`, `"Answer 1-4"`, `"Answer 1-5"` to be correct answers, and I'm using this to check if answer's correct or not...

```
switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.button5:
        clicks++;
        if(clicks > 0)
        beginn.setText("Next");
        break;
    case R.id.button1:
        if(answer == 1)
        correct++;
        else
        correct--;
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        if(answer == 2)
            correct++;
            else
            correct--;
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        if(answer == 3)
            correct++;
            else
            correct--;
        break;
    case R.id.button4:
        if(answer == 4)
            correct++;
            else
            correct--;
        break;
```

Basicly, I need to set my `answer` integer to something, how do I do that?

**EDIT:** I know it's `answer = number;` , but what number? How I check if it's `"Answer 1-1"`, after my array list has been shuffled? Without doing something like:

```
 if(answers_list[Type][0] == "Answer 1-1")
 answer = 1;
 else if(answers_list[Type][1] == "Answer 1-1")
 answer = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use a 2-dimensional array for this but instead a class to hold a question String, wrong answer Strings and a correct answer String. This class can have a method that returns a String array of potential answers that has been randomized, and can know which one is the correct one.

Comment: How do I randomize it then? Can you show me a code example, please?

Comment: @John: Myself, I'd create an ArrayList<String>, add all potential answer Strings to the array list, but the correct answer and all incorrect answers, and then simply call java.util.Arrays.shuffle(...) on my ArrayList. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a way to mark an answer as correct inside the list of lists. One method is to create an `Answer` class to encapsulate its text and a boolean correct/incorrect flag. Another is to alter the text in a way that won't appear in the text normally, for example prepend a `+` to the front of all correct answers.

Comment: Thanks! Everything's working now! All I did was ...   public boolean isCorrect(int button){
   for (int i = 0; i < correctList.length; i++){
    if(a1 == correctList[i] && button == 1 || a2 == correctList[i]  && button == 2
       || a3 == correctList[i]  && button == 3 || a4 == correctList[i]  && button == 4)
     return true;
   }
   return false;
  }

Comment: Cool. Don't forget to accept helpful/correct answers. And welcome to SO. :)